# Flutter onStretchTrigger not working. Build scheduled during frame

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

This code will work completely fine if I use **Refresh indicator OR Button tap**.

But wont work if use it inside **SliverAppBar for onStretchTrigger function**.

```
onStretchTrigger: () async {
 setState(() {
 myVariable = myFutureData();
 });
},
```

The error I get:

> I/flutter (31102): Build scheduled during frame.
>
> I/flutter (31102): While the widget tree was being built, laid out,
> and painted, a new frame was scheduled to rebuild the widget tree.
>
> I/flutter (31102): This might be because setState() was called from a
> layout or paint callback. If a change is needed to the widget tree, it
> should be applied as the tree is being built. Scheduling a change for
> the subsequent frame instead results in an interface that lags behind
> by one frame. If this was done to make your build dependent on a size
> measured at layout time, consider using a LayoutBuilder,
> CustomSingleChildLayout, or CustomMultiChildLayout.
>
> If, on the other hand, the one frame delay is the desired effect, for
> example because this is an animation, consider scheduling the frame in
> a post-frame callback using SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback or
> using an AnimationController to trigger the animation. I/flutter
> (31102): I/flutter (31102): #0
> WidgetsBinding._handleBuildScheduled.
> package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:747
>
> I/flutter (31102): #1      WidgetsBinding._handleBuildScheduled
> package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:770
>
> I/flutter (31102): #2      BuildOwner.scheduleBuildFor
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2476
>
> I/flutter (31102): #3      Element.markNeedsBuild
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4324
>
> I/flutter (31102): #4      State.setState
> package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1108
>
> I/flutter (31102): #5      _HomeScreenState.build.
> package:fesale/screens/screen_home.dart:197
>
> I/flutter (31102): #6      _HomeScreenState.build.
> package:fesale/screens/screen_home.dart:195
>
> I/flutter (31102): #7      RenderSliverPersistentHeader.layoutChild
> package:flutter/…/rendering/sliver_persistent_header.dart:257
>
> I/flutter (31102): #8
> RenderSliverFloatingPersistentHeader.performLayout
> package:flutter/…/rendering/sliver_persistent_header.dart:708
>
> I/flutter (31102): #9      RenderObject.layout
> package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1858
>
> I/flutter (31102): #10     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSeq

Please help could not find any solution for that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**INITIAL**: First of all: you don't need to put an `async` there since you are not making use of the `await` keyword, it's just a function call which return value is being assigned to your variable.

**UPDATE**: `onStretchTrigger` actually expects an `AsyncCallback` so for this use case the `async` keyword has to be used - sorry!

---

Second: your error message states what causes this and offers several solution:

> [...] This might be because setState() was called from a layout or paint callback. [...] consider scheduling the frame in a post-frame callback using **SchedulerBinding.addPostFrameCallback** [...]

So for now you can do:

```dart
SchedulerBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  setState(() => myVariable = myFutureData());
});
```

Comment: If i remove the async I need to return something otherwise ill get this error =>                   The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.

Comment: You are right! Just looked uo the documentation and `onStretchTrigger` expects an `AsyncCallback`, so async is actually necessary in this case, sorry!